# Plotting multiple lines on a single graph using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple lines on a single graph using matplotlib, primarily by following this tutorial: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/showcase/bachelors_degrees_by_gender.html#sphx-glr-gallery-showcase-bachelors-degrees-by-gender-py

However, I notice that the color sequence is hardcoded.

Is there anyway to call them by name instead ?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "call them by name"? What do you want to call and which name is it you are talking about? It's always hard to help without a proper problem description.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "call them by name" as writing `"red"`, or `"r"` instead of `"#ff0000"`(hex code for red), there are some colors which are recognized by `matplotlib`, namely

```
b: blue
g: green
r: red
c: cyan
m: magenta
y: yellow
k: black
w: white
```

You can read more about it [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/colors_api.html). You could also create a custom dictionary that you can map some other colors to their respective RGB/hex values.